# Reduced Rank Linear Discriminant Analysis vs Fisher Discriminant as mentioned in Element of Statistical learning section 4.3.3

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, discriminant-analysis

In ESL section 4.3.3 , Author gives three steps for finding optimal subspaces using LDA as below

1. compute the K × p matrix of class centroids M and the common covariance matrix W (for within-class covariance);
2. compute M<sup>**</sup> = MW<sup>-(1/2)</sup> using the eigen-decomposition of W;
3. compute B** the covariance matrix of M**(B for between-class covariance), and its eigen-decomposition B** = V*D<sub>B</sub>V∗<sup>T</sup>.The columns
   v<sub>ℓ</sub> of V<sup>*</sup> in sequence from first to last define the coordinates of the optimal subspaces

Author further states that "Fisher arrived at this decomposition via a different route, without referring to Gaussian distributions at all.  He posed the problem:
*Find the linear combination Z = a<sup>T</sup>X such that the betweenclass variance is maximized relative to the within-class variance*"

I think author is trying to establish link between Gaussian LDA and Fisher though I am not able to relate how 3 steps outlined above links to Fisher LDA.

Could any one explain 3 steps mentioned above and its relation to Fisher's LDA